# How can I perform an operation programatically when the value of a user field is changed?

Tags: hooks, 8

On my user accounts, I have a text field, `field_nickname`.  Users can change this at any time.

When they do change it, however, when the user account is saved I want to copy the old value for `field_nickname` to a text field accepting unlimited values, `field_nicknamehistory`.

In Drupal 7, you could do this in Rules by making a rule "on user update" and accessing the old value through the tokens in the rule interface.  However, Rules isn't here yet for Drupal 8, so I'm trying to do this in code.

I tried to do this with `hook_user_presave()` but I don't know how to get the old value to compare it against the new value:

```
function mymodule_user_presave(Drupal\user\UserInterface $entity) {
  // How do I get $previousnickname?
  if ($entity->get("field_nickname") !== $previousnickname) {
    $entity->get('field_nicknamehistory')->appendItem($entity->get($previousnickname));
  }
```

I looked through the API and found [onChange()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!lib!Drupal!Core!Entity!Plugin!DataType!EntityAdapter.php/function/EntityAdapter%3A%3AonChange/8), but I don't see how that would help me here.

Comment: `EntityAdapter` is a data type class; it can be used to create entity's properties, but you cannot used it for what you want to achieve.

Comment: I have updated my answer. It seems that what `content_translation_entity_presave()` does is a little excessive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Content translation module has code you could use, right in its `hook_entity_presave()` implementation (i.e. [`content_translation_entity_presave()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!modules!content_translation!content_translation.module/function/content_translation_entity_presave/8)).

```
if (!isset($entity->original)) {
  $entity->original = entity_load_unchanged($entity->entityType(), $entity->id());
}
```

In `$entity->original` you then find all the values that entity object had before being changed, as the documentation for [`entity_load_unchanged()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!includes!entity.inc/function/entity_load_unchanged/8) says:

> Loads the unchanged, i.e. not modified, entity from the database.
>
> Unlike [`entity_load()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21includes%21entity.inc/function/entity_load/8) this function ensures the entity is directly loaded from the database, thus bypassing any static cache. In particular, **this function is useful to determine changes** by comparing the entity being saved to the stored entity.

If you want to write code that will need less changes when passing to Drupal 9, you can use the following one, which replaces the call to `entity_load_unchanged()` (marked *deprecated*) with that function's code.

```
if (!isset($entity->original)) {
  $entity->original = \Drupal::entityManager()->getStorage($entity->entityType())->loadUnchanged($entity->id());
}
```

Also [`image_entity_presave()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21image%21image.module/function/image_entity_presave/8) uses `$entity->original`, but it doesn't load it if it has not been set.

```
$original_uuid = isset($entity->original) ? $entity->original->getSetting('default_image')['uuid'] : NULL;
```

Probably, you could simplify the code.

```
if (!isset($entity->original)) {
  // Get the old value of the field.
}
```

Looking at the method calling `hook_entity_presave()`, [`EntityStorageBase::doPreSave()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!lib!Drupal!Core!Entity!EntityStorageBase.php/function/EntityStorageBase%3A%3AdoPreSave/8), the latter seems a more correct code.

```
  $id = $entity->id();

  // Track the original ID.
  if ($entity->getOriginalId() !== NULL) {
    $id = $entity->getOriginalId();
  }

  // Track if this entity exists already.
  $id_exists = $this->has($id, $entity);

  // Omissis

  // Load the original entity, if any.
  if ($id_exists && !isset($entity->original)) {
    $entity->original = $this->loadUnchanged($id);
  }

  // Allow code to run before saving.
  $entity->preSave($this);
  $this->invokeHook('presave', $entity);
```

`EntityStorageBase::doPreSave()` already sets `$entity->original` for entities that aren't new; the code used from `content_translation_entity_presave()` seems excessive.

Comment: I don't know why  content_translation_entity_presave() does that. For an update, $entity->original should *always* exist. And for a new entity, it can't since there is no original entity yet. So instead of that, just make sure with !$entity->isNew() that you are indeed updating.

Comment: There are just two implementations of `hook_entity_presave()`; the other one doesn't set `$entity->original`. Considering what `EntityStorageBase::doPreSave()` does, I would say it's enough to to use `if (isset($entity->original)) { /* */ }`. I added a note about that.

Answer (score 0):

Based on @kiamlaluno's answer, here is the code that worked for me (note that it adds a timestamp when recording the change to the field):

```
function mymodule_user_presave(Drupal\user\UserInterface $entity) {
  if (!$entity->isNew() && ($entity->get('field_nickname')->value !== ($entity->original->get('field_nickname')->value))) {
    $record = $entity->original->get('field_nickname')->value.' '.date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
    $entity->get('field_nicknamehistory')->appendItem($record);
  }
}
```